# is there a jcarousel plugin for wordpress that loads dynamic images

Tags: gallery

i got a client who wants to upload the images to the jcarousel gallery rather than have them imputed statically through HTML. is there such a plugin that would let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

[**Carousel Gallery (jQuery)**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/carousel-gallery-jquery/) plugin tweaks WordPress' built-in gallery function so your client could upload the images to it.

Comment: it says is modifies the wordpress gallery and turns it into a jcarousel type thing. will they be able to add images elsewhere and it not show with jcarousel? also would this support albums because they want 3 sections of galleries like this as jcarousel and each album havine its own set of images

Comment: yes they will be able to add images normally , and each post has its own gallery/album